# Problema al recorrer un array dentro de otro array , ¿como resolver?

Tags: javascript, array

estoy trabajando en una pequeña aplicacion qen la cual estoy enviando un pedido y necesito ver ese pedido en una tabla, estoy utilizando firebase y ya pude enviar los datos y enviar el arreglo de los productos seleccionados, pero tengo un problema al querer mostrar estos datos, el arreglo es como esto.

```
pedidos[{
   uid: ffklfnwlgnwenfmiij5tn5jn,
   pedido:[
      {codigo: 12345, nombre: "producto1"},
      {codigo: 67890, nombre: "producto2"},
   ]
}]
```

cuando recorro estos datos con .map no tengo problema, solo cuando quiero mapear el arreglo que esta adentro "pedido"
si hago un console.log() a console.log(pedidos.map((x, index) => x.pedido)); me aparece algo asi:

```
    Array [ (3) […] ]
​
0: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { nombre: "ADEROGYL  SOL 3ML/ CON 5 AMP", codigo: "0007501165003040" }
​​
1: Object { codigo: "0007501080111462", nombre: "JUST FOR MEN BARBA Y BIGOTE B-30 CASTANO MEDIO CON 60 ML" }
​​
2: Object { nombre: "JUST FOR MEN BARBA Y BIGOTE B-35 CASTANO OSCURO MEDIO CON 60 ML", codigo: "0007501080111431" }
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

quiero pensar que el problema es que es por como aparece el arreglo.

de antemano agradezco esta plataforma, me han ayudado bastante.

Comment: No acabo de entender el problema: te está mostrando cada uno de los arrays correctamente. Si lo que quieres es imprimirlos de un modo más "bonito" en la consola, podrías usar algo como `console.log(JSON.stringify(objeto))`

Answer (score 0):

por cierto, el codigo que pusiste es incorrecto, da error:

```
pedidos[{
   uid: ffklfnwlgnwenfmiij5tn5jn,
   pedido:[
      {codigo: 12345, nombre: "producto1"},
      {codigo: 67890, nombre: "producto2"},
   ]
}]
```

en todo caso, para tener una salida como la que muestras deberia ser:

```
let pedidos = [{
   uid: "ffklfnwlgnwenfmiij5tn5jn",
   pedido:[
      {codigo: 12345, nombre: "producto1"},
      {codigo: 67890, nombre: "producto2"},
   ]
}]
```

suponiendo que "ffklfnwlgnwenfmiij5tn5jn" sea un string y no una variable.

Entonces con eso puedes acceder a los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
//para acceder al arreglo pedidos
console.log(pedidos.map(e => e.pedido));

//y por ejemplo para acceder a todos productos del pedido
console.log(pedidos.map(e => e.pedido.map(e => e.nombre)));
```